# Why my tracking service freezes when the phone moves?

Tags: android

I have developed a service which includes timer task and runs after every 5 minutes for keeping tracking record of the device, every five minutes it adds a record to the database.

My service is working fine when the phone is not moving i.e it gives records after every 5 minutes as it should be. But i have noticed that when the phone is on move it updates the points after 10 or  20 minutes , i.e whenever the user stops in his way whenever he is on the move.

Do service freezes on the move, if yes! how is whatsapp messenger managing it??
Please help!
i am writing my onstart method. please help

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    mLocationClient.connect();

    final Handler handler_service = new Handler();
    timer_service = new Timer();
    TimerTask thread_service = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler_service.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        some function of tracking
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer_service.schedule(thread_service, 1000, service_timing);







    //sync thread

    final Handler handler_sync = new Handler();
    timer_sync = new Timer();
    TimerTask thread_sync = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler_sync.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        //connecting to the central server for updation
                        Connect();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer_sync.schedule(thread_sync,2000, sync_timing);



}
```

Comment: You swallow a possible exception thrown by `Connect` silently. Maybe it contains useful information to nail down the problem.

Comment: I have two timer task , the first one is for storing the values into local database i.e sqlite .. if my device is not moving local database stores the values very fine . but on move it misses many values.  (I am deleting the value from the local database row by row , matching if the statement executes returns true for connect then only delete from local)